is there anyone know about how to save the captured image, recorded audio and location address to save in google drive using python
enter image description here
Description:
I'm encountering an issue with my application where I receive a "redirect_uri_mismatch" error with the status code 400. I'm using [Visual studio code] for my application.
I've verified that the redirect URI configured in my application settings matches the one specified in my code. Despite this, I still encounter the error when attempting to access the app.
Any insights into what might be causing this error and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.
What I Tried:
Verified that the redirect URI specified in my application matches the one configured in my application settings.
Checked for any typos or discrepancies in the redirect URI.
Double-checked the client ID and client secret used in my application.
Reviewed the documentation and any relevant tutorials for the framework/platform I'm using to ensure I'm following the correct steps for OAuth authentication.
Tried accessing the app from different environments (e.g., local development, staging server) to rule out any environment-specific issues.
What I Expected:
I expected that with the correct configuration of redirect URIs and OAuth client credentials, I would be able to access my application without encountering the "redirect_uri_mismatch" error. However, despite ensuring the accuracy of these details, the error persists.

Click error details this is a configuration issue https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ?si=qCGIDILL8wmRL-Gd

Thanks for your help but i can't solve this. It this needed to create a web page of my project and i create only the API creditionals service and i didn't know what i want to do can you please expalin the whole process

Edit your question and include your code

Sorry for that, but I can't understand what you are trying to say. Can you explain a little further?

I need to see the code for your application in order to help you.  Without seeing your code its hard to help

How do i send a code mam. If it's ok for you can you send your mail ID or something else

you edit your question by clicking edit on it and you put a [example] within your question.

ok mam i will try my best
